# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, design, logo

When we make it out of beta our site will receive a new logo and site design. According to [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) (#6) we can offer suggestions all the way down to finished design proposals.

It would be nice to hear from [P&T](http://pixelandtonic.com/) about how much community involvement they would like from us before we get started of course and assuming they want suggestions then this is where we can talk about what the logo and site design should look like.

*Note: It could take a long time to get out of public beta, as has been the case with [EESE](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/) for example but, that may not be the case with Craft. With that said, and depending on what P&T has to say on the matter, it would be cool to get the process started now while we have plenty of time.*

Comment: I’m sure there are people in this community that could come up with a nicer design than we could. I’m not worried about it looking “too official” – we’re behind this site 100%, and even offered for SE to use our “C” logo in the site’s favicon.

Comment: Your builtwithcraft.com, the Docs and the Control Panel designs are gorgeous, @Brandon! And I'd love to see `Proxima Nova` as the main font here!

Answer (score 6):

I was mulling on this myself, and I was kind of leaning toward making it looking similar to the official Craft site, or possible like the Control Panel. I'm not sure if that would look too official though. At the very least, the Craft look tends to lean towards lots of white with some muted dark blues and red accents.